# Google wallet number

Tags: google-wallet

The help page "About the virtual card" on Google Wallet says:

> For certain online purchases, your full credit or debit card information won't be shared with the seller. Instead, Google will complete your payment using a virtual debit MasterCard or Discover card number. This number is known as the Google Wallet Virtual Card, and is issued by the Bancorp Bank.

For security reasons I would like to use this virtual card number to buy online in place of my credit/debit card number. However I can't find anywhere on the site what this number is. Is the account holder even allowed to give this number directly into online shops that ask for a credit card?